# How to make jquery galleryview click-able?

Tags: jquery

I am using this http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/,

I need to insert link to every picture so I added link like below but it doesn't work. Is there anyway I can click on the image to jump somewhere?

```
<ul id="myGallery">
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.spaceforaname.com/galleryview/img/photos/bp1.jpg" alt="Lone Tree Yellowstone" /></a>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.spaceforaname.com/galleryview/img/photos/bp1.jpg" alt="Lone Tree Yellowstone" /></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the .js of Galleryview:

1. Below line 22 of the jquery.galleryview-3.0-dev.js, insert these lines:

   `this.customlink = img.attr('customlink');`
   `this.haslink = img.attr('haslink');`
2. Next, below line 467, insert the following lines:

   `var address = "'" + gvImage.customlink + "'";`
   `var js = "window.location.assign(" + address + ");";`
   `if(gvImage.haslink=='true') {img.attr("onclick", js);}`
3. The HTML code that triggers Galleryview will now be as follows:

   `<ul id="myGallery">`
      `<li><img haslink="true" customlink="somelink" src="images/1.jpg" alt="Lone Tree Yellowstone" />`
      `<li><img haslink="true" customlink="somelink" src="images/2.jpg" alt="Lone Tree Yellowstone" />`
   `</ul>`

If you want to treat the image of the gallery as a link, set "`haslink=true`".
The "`customlink`" attribute is used in the same way as the "`href`" attribute.
You can also surround `ul` with a `div` and style it with "`cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;`"
so the user realizes that the image is a link.

Hope this helps!

Comment: of course, you can ignore 'haslink' completely and change the condition inside if to 'typeof(gvImage.customlink)!='undefined' && gvImage.customlink!=null'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('img').click(function(){
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
});
```